# SOAP webservice consuming vb.net

Tags: vb.net, soap

I am new to SOAP webservices, I was given a folder which consists of WSDL, .xsd files. and asked to consume a end point url. "https://abc-bus-dev.xyz.org/service/admin/Update/v", From the WSDL i am able to create a proxy classes for body part but from envelop to body i dont see anything in the wsdl. When i checked with them they asked to create a custom header. I was not sure how to create customer header with name spaces. Also can you please let me know how to add the header to the body and form the XML and send the request and receive response. Can any one please guide me so i can work accordingly and proceed further. i am really in a bad and tough situation, i am writing the code in vb.net
The soap request look like below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://testing.testing.ws.testing.com/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>Testing</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>123456</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <trans:Method1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:UserinfoId>123456</com:UserinfoId>
         <sub:params>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <name>Testing</name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <value>98765-45678</value>
         </sub:params>      
</trans: Method1 >
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the vb.net project and select add --> service reference.  It will generate the classes needed to call the webservice.

Then you call the webservice like this. Replace ServiceReference1 with what you named the service.  Replace SoapClient with the name service Client

```
  Dim service = new ServiceReference1.SoapClient
```

The url you posted is not publicly accessible so I could not add a service reference to it

Comment: Thank you for your update. The url what we have in wsdl is different and the url that we need to hit is datapower url. Already i ahve follwed above process and imported and created a proxy classes to create an object. Currently i am struck at creating the custom header having the usertoken details.  can you let me know how to create a custom header with name spaces.